# Fitting's Lemma version for pseudocompact modules or linearly compact modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, representation-theory, noncommutative-algebra, division-algebras

Let $R$ be a pseudocompact ring or a linearly compact ring. Is there a version of Fitting's Lemma for pseudocompoact or linearly compact $R$-modules?